# Flexigrid Plugin - Change position of resize bar and mouse movements

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

I am trying to use the flexigrid table, the problem is that I do not want it at the top or middle of my page but at the bottom.

So I need to reposition the resize bar from the bottom of the table to the top and change the resize movements(since this table seems to have been created to only be positioned at the top of a page pulling the bar down enlarges the div and pulling/pushing it up makes it smaller, I need this in reverse).

I've been searching for a fix for this for awhile and have not come across anything that even addresses this problem. If possible I would like to do this without making changes to the flexigrid plugin(if this isn't possible then its fine).

(I'm using the code straight from the flexigrid site, but will post just in case something is wrong or I can just add a bit of code there to fix this)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sentaku_results").flexigrid({
        //url: 'post2.php',
        //dataType: 'json',
        colModel : [
            {display: 'Count', name : 'column1', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
            {display: '地図', name : 'column2', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
            {display: '大字名', name : 'column3', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
            {display: '小字名', name : 'column4', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
            {display: '本番', name : 'column5', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
            {display: '枝番', name : 'column6', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
            {display: '孫番', name : 'column7', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
            {display: 'ひ孫番', name : 'column8', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
            {display: '所有者氏名', name : 'column9', width : 220, sortable : true, align: 'center'}
        ],
        buttons : [
            //{name: 'Add', bclass: 'add', onpress : test},
            //{name: 'Delete', bclass: 'delete', onpress : test},
            {separator: true},
            {name: 'A', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'B', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'C', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'D', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'E', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'F', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'G', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'H', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'I', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'J', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'K', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'L', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'M', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'N', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'O', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'P', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'Q', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'R', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'S', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'T', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'U', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'V', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'W', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'X', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'Y', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: 'Z', onpress: sortAlpha},
            {name: '#', onpress: sortAlpha}
        ],
        searchitems : [
            {display: 'Count', name : 'column1'},
            {display: '地図', name : 'column2'},
            {display: '大字名', name : 'column3'},
            {display: '小字名', name : 'column4'},
            {display: '本番', name : 'column5'},
            {display: '枝番', name : 'column6'},
            {display: '孫番', name : 'column7'},
            {display: 'ひ孫番', name : 'column8'},
            {display: '所有者氏名', name : 'column9', isdefault: true}
        ],
        sortname: "Count",
        sortorder: "asc",
        usepager: true,
        title: '土地情報検索結果',
        useRp: true,
        rp: 10,
        showTableToggleBtn: true,
        width: $('#search_results').innerWidth(),
        height: 50
    }); 
});
function sortAlpha(com){ 
    $('#flex1').flexOptions({newp:1, params:[{name:'letter_pressed', value:com}, {name:'qtype',value:$('select[name=qtype]').val()}]});
    $("#flex1").flexReload(); 
}
function test(com,grid){
    if (com=='Delete'){
        if($('.trSelected',grid).length>0){
            if(confirm('Delete ' + $('.trSelected',grid).length + ' items?')){
                var items = $('.trSelected',grid);
                var itemlist ='';
                for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){
                    itemlist+= items[i].id.substr(3)+",";
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "delete.php",
                    data: "items="+itemlist,
                    success: function(data){
                        alert("Query: "+data.query+" - Total affected rows: "+data.total);
                        $("#sentaku_results").flexReload();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if(com=='Add'){
        alert('Add New Item Action');
    }
}
```

(Apologies if this is a trivial question; I'm not used to using jQuery/jQuery plugins)

Thanks for your help

**Update:** I have been able to move the position of the vertical resize bar to the top by changing the following code in the flexigrid.js file

Line 1181
*Before* `$(g.gDiv).prepend(g.mDiv);` *Changed to* `$(g.vDiv).after(g.mDiv);`

and then instead of prepend the Title div to the top of the container, I prepend the vGrip div

Line 1083
*Before* `$(g.bDiv).after(g.vDiv);` *Changed to* `$(g.gDiv).prepend(g.vDiv);`

Sorry its taken awhile to update this post, been working on a few other projects simultaneously. Still looking for help on the mouse movement during resize.

Comment: I believe you have to manipulate the source code of the Flexigrid.

Comment: ...I was worried I would get this response lol, any tips on changing the api?